# Masonry blocks shift while loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

Hey guys having a problem with masonry plugin.

I'm trying to load the simple layout using percentPosition: true; and the problem is when everything loads, layout loads without the gutter and adds it later which causes all images to shift and it looks quiet annoying.
cant seem to figure out the solution to load it the way that nothing would shift. Bellow is the code:

and here is the link: [dev3.oaknyc.com](http://dev3.oaknyc.com/)

```
<div class="section group">
<div class="col-sizer"></div>
<div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
<div class="col col-span2">
    <img src={{media url="img/10-21/1.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="blog/introducing-hope-shoes-more/"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Introducing:</span>
                <h3>HOPE for women + men</h3>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <img src={{media url="img/10-21/2.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="women/new-items.html"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Just In:</span>
                <h3>HENRIK VIBSKOV</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <img src={{media url="img/10-21/3.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="women/designers/oak.html"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Shop:</span>
                <h3>OAK Collection Women</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <img src={{media url="img/10-21/4.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="men/designers/oak-collection.html"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Shop:</span>
                <h3> OAK Collection Men</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col col-span2">
    <img src={{media url="wysiwyg/blanco/img/10-21/5.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="women/designers/laura-siegel.html"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Shop:</span>
                <h3>Laura Siegel</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <img src={{media url="img/10-21/6.jpg"}}>
    <a href={{store url="women/accessories.html"}}>
        <div class="txt-overlay">
            <div class="txt-title">
                <span>Shop:</span>
                <h3>Women's Accessories</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.section').imagesLoaded(function(){
            jQuery('.section').masonry({
              // options
              columnWidth: '.col-sizer',
              itemSelector: '.col',
              gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
              percentPosition: true
            });
        });
     });
     //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: No answer, but I had the same problem. Ended up ignoring it :/

Comment: :( so annoying!